# Problem with initializing 2d array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble with a project that uses a 2d array of objects.

The object constructor:

```
public BlackoutWindow(boolean l, int r, int c) {
    lightOn = l;
    row = r;
    column = c;
```

The problem is here while initializing for loop:

```
    for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < c; j++) {
            board[i][j] = new BlackoutWindow(Math.random() > 0.5, i, j);
        }
    }
```

The code runs fine if r==c but not if r!=c. It's not a compile error but the output is not correct. The variables i and j should match the r and c but that is not happening. Here is what it looks like with r=4 c=5: [Program Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEEjD.png).

If I swap the i and j in the line:

```
new BlackoutWindow(Math.random() > 0.5, i, j);
```

Then the output looks correct but it messes up the rest of the program and doesn't make sense in general.

Here is the draw() method for BlackoutWindow class:

```
public void draw()
{
    StdDraw.setPenColor(lightOn ? StdDraw.YELLOW : StdDraw.BLACK);
    StdDraw.filledRectangle(row+0.5,column+0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}
```

And here is the draw method for the other Gameboard class that contains the for loop:

```
public void draw()
{
    for (int i=0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < this.board[0].length; j++) {

            board[i][j].draw(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear i and j in the BlackoutWindow method are used to hold position and they should match the array index values but they only seem to account for the smaller of the two values. So for r=5, c=7, the grid that is drawn only displays as a 5x5 instead of the 5x7 that is expected.

Comment: The for loops assigning the board values seems to look good. So the problem must be in the method that draws it, and we cannot see that method now. Please include the drawing method.

Comment: @itwasntme I have edited the post to include the two draw methods.

Comment: This one also looks good. What about the draw method of `BlackoutWindow`? If your are saying that swapping the i and j when calling constructor works, than prehaps the problem is inside that method.

Comment: @itwasntme I included that method in the edit right above the other draw method. It is short and simple, just uses StdDraw to draw a filled rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have considers `i` as rows and `j` as columns. So we perceive the `i` as vertical variable and `j` as horizontal variable.

The underlying drawing method (the one in `StdDraw.filledRectangle`) takes the first two parameters as coordinates of Cartesian system.

So the first coordinate in that system (commonly called as `x`) is referring to the horizontal axis and second (an `y`) passes the unit on the vertical axis.

Therefore, when you swapped the `i` with `j` it worked fine, because the `i`-rows was referring to the vertical coordinate and `j`-columns to the horizontal one.

To make sure, I looked at the [documentation](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html#filledRectangle-double-double-double-double-) of `StdDraw.filledRectangle` and as standard the first parameter refers to x-coordinate and second to y-coordinate of Cartesian system.

You didn't tell why the swap messes up the rest and why it doesn't make sense, but  hopefully, with above explanation it makes sense (if not, comment and I'll try to tell more) and why it messes up the rest?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This cleared up what was going wrong this whole time! I have been coding with the intention that x and y were rows and cols respectively! Your post cleared it all up for me and I made edits and it runs perfectly now! Your the best!

Comment: Sorry I meant to accept it but I have now! I +1 but apparently because I have less than 15 rep it doesn't show but says it does record! Thanks again!